# How to retrieve data in ordered manner from Set in java?

Tags: java, collections

I cannot use sorted set because `getAllResults()` method is returning set..

```
Set<ITestResult> failedTestResults =   con.getTestContext().getFailedTests().getAllResults();

for (ITestResult failedTestResult : failedTestResults) {
    // To get failed test parameters
    Object[] failedTestParameters = failedTestResult.getParameters();
    // To get method name (Not sure on this, getMethod() also may work)
    String FailedMethodName = failedTestResult.getName(); // (There is also //.getTestName())
    // To get exception (Not sure about this)
    Throwable exception = failedTestResult.getThrowable();
    // You can do whatever you want with these
    //System.out.println("Failed TestName :" + FailedMethodName);
    list.add("Failed TestName :" + FailedMethodName);

}
```

Comment: The question isn't clear, please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why not get the Set and then sort it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I cannot use sorted set because `getAllResults()` method is returning set.*

If `ITestResult` happens to extend/implement `Comparable<ITestResult>` interface, then *natural ordering* can be applied and `SortedSet` may be
constructed as follows:

```java
// interface ITestResult extends Comparable<ITestResult> { ... } 
SortedSet<ITestResult> failedTestResults = new TreeSet<>(
        con.getTestContext().getFailedTests().getAllResults()
);
```

Otherwise, an empty `SortedSet` can be constructed with custom `Comparator<ITestResult>` by some property and all the entries returned by `getAllResults()` can be added using `Collections::addAll`:

```java
SortedSet<ITestResult> failedTestResults = new TreeSet<>(
        Comparator.comparing(ITestResult::getName)
); // comparing by name only

failedTestResults.addAll(con.getTestContext().getFailedTests().getAllResults());
```

The code snippets work fine for older Java versions without Stream API.

---

The sorted set may be retrieved with the help of Stream API using `Collectors.toCollection` with the supplier of the tree set with the custom comparator as shown above:

```java
SortedSet<ITestResult> sorted = con.getTestContext().getAllResults()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(
        () -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(ITestResult::getName))
    ));
```

---

Or, possibly, if the test results should be simply converted into a list according to the line `list.add("Failed TestName :" + FailedMethodName);`:

```java
List<String> failedMethods = con.getTestContext().getAllResults()
    .stream()
    .map(ITestResult::getName)
    .sorted()
    .map("Failed TestName :"::concat) // add method name after the prefix
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```